# Pandas: How to change some type observations in a column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, types

I have a Dataframe where a column is full of observations which could be numbers or strings. Currently, the data type of this column (called Code) is an object. How can I change the data type of this column to integers just for those observations that are numbers? I tried the following code:

```
df['Code'].astype(str).astype(int)
```

But of course it doesn't work because it tries to converts the strings into numbers.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you add some data sample with expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using str.isnumeric() to create a mask of True or False?  You won’t be able to change part of the records data type because pandas (and numpy) require that everything in the column is the same data type. You could save only the numbers as a new dataframe and then convert the column type.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_isnumeric.htm

Sorry I can’t code backticks on my phone.

#### create Boolean mask to filter numbers only

mask_numeric = df[‘code’].str.isnumeric()

#### filter only the True records in the mask

df_numbers = df.loc[mask_numeric]

Comment: I understand, I didn't know you can't change part of the record data type. Thank you